# Delete "Not assigned" Contact Group on Samsung Galaxy S9+

Tags: samsung, contacts, delete, samsung-galaxy-s-9

On my Samsung Galaxy S9+ in my Contacts app, I have a group called "Not assigned" with 712 contacts.  How do I delete this group and its contacts that are not in other groups?

These contacts are not sync to Google.  The rest of the contacts are.

[image: screenshot of Not assigned group]

Answer (score 1):

If you got those 'Not assigned' contact from a google account then you are in luck.

- Log in back to that google account to which those 'Not assigned' contacts belong.
- Once you log in, those 'Not assigned' will be assigned back to the google account that you just added.
- Select that google account in the display option.
- Now you'll be able to bulk select all contacts and delete them.
  (Note: it will also be deleted from your synced google account but you can easily and quickly recover it from https://contacts.google.com/trash or from VCF file)
- Now you can remove your google account from your Samsung device without leaving any 'Not assigned' contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution I was looking for, but I tapped on each contact and deleted it.  This required 4 taps per contact.  My wrist was getting sore half way through.  It took me about 1 hour.